# hide all class members that aren't a child of (this) element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several elements on a page all structured like the following:

```
<div>
    <button>
    <table id="table1" class='tableClass'>
        misc child elements
    </table>
</div>
```

This is repeated 6 times.

When the `<button>` is clicked, I want to toggle the visibility of `#table1`, as well as hide ALL `.tableClass`'es that are NOT `#table1`

--

This is what I have so far, which is fired when the `<button>` is clicked..

`$('.tableClass').not(this.children()).fadeOut();`

The problem is I need to access the appropriate `.tableClass`. The `this.children()` line isn't what I want since I know the table is not a child of the button, but I can't think of a straightforward way.

I know this is pretty straight forward but I'm sleep deprived and haven't had my coffee :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: typo. Was not in the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw the other answers but here's another approach:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('#table1').toggle();
    $('.tableClass[id != "table1"]').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: This is what worked best for my situation. Simple, straightforward and succinct and not bound to button location. Thanks!

Comment: That's not a reusable code, wich mean you have to copy it 6 times for the other 6 `div`'s...

Comment: It depends what the poster means by repeating six times. I took that to mean a set of tables but only one button. If that's the case, the code is perfectly fine. If there is a button for each set, then you would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var table = $(this).closest('div').find('.tableClass').fadeIn();
$('.tableClass').not(table).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Like the other answer, this depends on the physical placement of the button.